# How to use \multirow with \hline in some columns

Tags: longtable, multirow

I want to have a multirow in front of a table, but always get horizontal lines over all columns.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{ | p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{5cm} | }
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Multirow} & singlerow-1 & singelow-2\\
        \hline
        & singlerow-1 & singelow-2 \\
        \hline
        & singlerow-1 & singelow-2 \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Outcome:

[image: outcome]

How can the lines in the first coloumn be removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{| p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{5cm} | }
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Multi row} & Single row-1 & Single row-2 \\ \cline{2-3} 
        & Single row-1 & Single row-2 \\ \cline{2-3} 
        & Single row-1 & Single row-2 \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

To get:
[image]

Comment: @MMM Good luck TEXing!!